# invisible characters in string

Tags: c++, c, linux, string

I have got a glsl compilation error becasue a fragment of the code which I have copied from somewhere has contained invisible characetrs. When I have printed all characters of the following code:`memoryBarrierShared​();`I have got:

```
memoryBarrierShared​���();
```

I use gedit when creating a shader files. How to explain that ? Do you know some text editor which can show me such invisible characters ?

Comment: Try changing the enconding used by `gedit` until the characters are not invisible anymore. This is a very dumb approach, but it will quickly solve the problem.

Comment: Try `od -c yourfile`,

Comment: vim shows you these characters. On windows, even Notepad is showing up these characters

Comment: Also sublime is a good editor for both Windows and Linux

Comment: It's far more likely your printing code contains a bug, and these are probably binary zeroes -- not *meant* to be seen and not present "in" the function name.